# Android Listview only shows one page and can't scroll down

Tags: android, database, listview

I have this very strange problem, I made a listview with simplecursoradapter to show show items from the database, I have abot 25 row,and the lisview only shows ten rows to fill the screen and cannot scroll down.

I've been stuck here 4 1 week,plz help

Activity shows listview

```
channellist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Channel);

        mDB = new ChannelDB(this);

        String[] columns = {mDB.KEY_ID, mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_PATH, mDB.KEY_DBLINK};
        String   table   = mDB.channelS_TABLE;

        c = mDB.getHandle().query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.channelview,
                c,
                new String[] {mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_DBLINK},
                new int[] {R.id.poster, R.id.channel, R.id.douban});

        adapter.setViewBinder(new ChannelViewBinder(this));

        channellist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My database table and key

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "channelDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String channelS_TABLE = "channels";

    private static final String CREATE_channelS_TABLE = "create table "+channelS_TABLE+" ("
                                         +KEY_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
                                         +KEY_POSTER+" blob not null, "
                                         +KEY_CHANNEL+" text not null unique, "
                                         +KEY_DBLINK+" integer not null, "
                                         +KEY_PATH+" integer not null);";
```

the most curious point is I got this from logcat every time

```
12-06 12:07:13.299: DEBUG/skia(1009): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

which means the BitArray from the database return null

But when I set LIMIT to the query, another page shows and the pictures are ok, which means all images can be transfered from database to imageview,so I don't understand, why this happens???

And I just tried to remove images from the query and the listview still in one page and can't scroll

channelViewVinder.java

```
public class ChannelViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    private ChannelDB mDB;
    private Context mContext = null;


    public ChannelViewBinder(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, final Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            mDB = new ChannelDB(mContext);
                if(view instanceof ImageView) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                        byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length));
                        return true;
                }

              if(view instanceof ImageButton) {
                           ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view;
                        ib.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {     
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {


                                String[] columns = {mDB.KEY_ID, mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_PATH, mDB.KEY_DBLINK};
                                String   table   = mDB.channelS_TABLE;

                                Cursor c = mDB.getHandle().query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

                                String dblink = c.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mDB.KEY_DBLINK));
                                Log.i("ChannelViewBinder", "path = " + dblink);
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setClass(mContext, Doubanframe.class);
                                Bundle bunde = new Bundle();
                                bunde.putString("dblink",dblink);
                                intent.putExtras(bunde);
                                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

and this is how I insert an entry

```
Bitmap sherlock = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sherlock);

mDB.createchannelEntry(new ChannelPoster(sherlock, "xxxx" ,"http://appkon.com/hdtvs/channel/bigbang1.xml"  ,"http://movie.douban.com/subject/5372374/" ));
```

and this is the channelposter

```
public class ChannelPoster {
    private Bitmap poster;
    private String channel;
    private String path;
    private String dblink;

    public ChannelPoster(Bitmap pi, String c, String p, String d) {
        poster = pi;
        channel = c;
        path = p;
        dblink = d;
    }

    public Bitmap getPoster() { return poster; }
    public String getChannel() { return channel; }
    public String getPath() { return path; }
    public String getDBlink() { return dblink; }
}
```

Comment: I'v got two questions. The frist is: why do you use `startManagingCursor()` in your `Activity` and what effect do you want to achieve when you define `KEY_POSTER` column with `blob not null` when you create your DB?

Comment: I am using startManagingCursor() to let the activity manage and use the cursor and KEY_POSTER is an image,so it has to be BLOB type,and I decode images into bitarray and stock it into the database when inserting it

Comment: Do you put the ListView inside a scrollView?

Comment: Well, firstly startManagingCursor() is deprecated method as described in official documentation, secondly could you add a code snippet where you encode your image to ByteArray and also it would be great if you show your `ChanelViewBinder` implementation

Comment: no,I didn't put the ListView inside a scrollView

Comment: @teoretik: only on Honeycomb and above. startManagingCursor is still valid, and would not cause such a problem anyway.

Comment: I've edited the post and add some code snippet you want

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong do you use one image `R.drawable.sherlock` for all of your entries? It seems like error: `12-06 12:07:13.299: DEBUG/skia(1009): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` occures because of bad decoding of this image

Comment: Pardon didn't see code string from `ChanelViewBinder`: `iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length));` and I still don't see a snippet where you encode your `Bitmap` to byte[] for insert to DB.

Comment: no,I use different image for each entry and as I said, I used LIMIT to query each 10 rows of the listview and all images turns ok

Comment: I presume that common ammount of bytes which you put into one Blob field in DB is bigger than it should be so to dispel all doubts I need to look how do you encode your image for putting it to DB

Comment: Oh another one question, why don't you return `true` value from `setViewValue()` method if view is `ImageButton` as you do it in `ImageView` case, but return false?

Comment: Can we talk in a chat or using IM? I am now stocking image resource name instead of bitarrays but the problem remain,so it's not about the image, maybe it's beacause the adapter

Comment: my gtalk is wangharp@gmail.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5619/discussion-between-oratis-and-teoretik)